# Use local TEXMFDIST as repository for install-tl

Tags: texlive, installing, texmf

I downloaded and extracted a full TEXMFDIST tree from ftp://tug.org/texlive/historic/2020/texlive-20200406-texmf.tar.xz (for reproducibility and not depending on net install).

Can I use `install-tl` for creating a new TDS by sourcing all packages from this local TEXMFDIST?

I found that `install-tl` and `tlmgr` do have a [`--repository` option](https://tug.org/texlive/doc/tlmgr.html#OPTIONS) but I can't understand if this TEXMFDIST can be specified as a repository somehow.

Background: I'd like to create several TDS trees (with different schemes) by slicing a single local full TEXMFDIST tree.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *can* use an existing installation as repository but not just TEXMFDIST, since the installer uses stuff from the tlpkg tree, but it is better to download a TL ISO from http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire.html

Comment: Is it possible to add that `tlpkg` tree stuff to that TEXMFDIST to create a usable TDS? If yes, how can I do that? :)

Comment: No. I see that if you use an installation as an unpacked repository then you are also going to need the binaries. I believe you can only skip the generated texmf-var and texmf-config with impunity.

Comment: What binaries would be needed needed? I'd be building the format files myself (using my custom binaries).

Comment: With respect to install-tl, I'm looking to have a local repository by downloading as few files as possible :) Preferrably - a single large tarball, pinned to a specific date.

Comment: Just get the iso from http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire.html

Comment: Oh, that's a good idea! Then I would be able to point `install-tl` repository switch to this mounted ISO to slice it, right?

Comment: Yes. Of course I should have suggested this rightaway. Note that the iso is not runnable out of the box.

Comment: What do you mean by "runnable"? That it doesn't contain the binaries?

Comment: It is an installer, not a live TL system. And I edited my original answer.

Comment: I've tried using installer from the iso (along with `--repository` switch and home-dir profile), but it doesn't work because it still tries to write to some system locations (?): https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/600792/install-tl-from-iso-in-non-root-env. Would you know how to do this properly?